# Align text to center with padding on both sides

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

Is there an easy way to align text to the center with padding on both sides, with the column width being the longest line from the input?

For example, this:

```
aaa
bbbb
c
ddddd
ee
```

will turn into this (the dots represent spaces):

```
.aaa.
bbbb.
..c..
ddddd
.ee..
```

Any tool is fine. Be it `sed` or `awk` or a bunch of `coreutils` tools.

**Edit**: I think some of you misunderstood the output. The output is padded with *spaces*, not dots. I've used dots here just to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, as posted in my [comment to Thor's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94748/align-text-to-center-with-padding-on-both-sides/94751?noredirect=1#comment143995_94751):

```
awk -v M="`wc -L file`" '{ printf "%*s%*s", (M+length)/2, $0, (M-length+1)/2+1, "\n" }' < file
```

I feel it solves the problem elegantly and succinctly, and therefore I'm reposting it as an answer.

Comment: `wc -L` is `wc --max-line-length` supported by GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way you could do it with awk (*pad.awk*):

```awk
# Determine length of longest line
FNR == NR { if(length > M) M = length; next }

# Pad each line according current line length (L) and longest line (M)
{
  L = M - length;
  for(i=1; i<=int(L/2); i++)
    printf "."
  printf "%s", $0
  for(i=1; i<=int(L/2+.5); i++)
    printf "."
  printf "\n"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f pad.awk infile infile
```

Output:

```
.aaa.
bbbb.
..c..
ddddd
.ee..
```

If you have GNU wc available, the longest line can more efficiently be found with `wc -L`. That is, drop the first line of *pad.awk* and run awk like this:

```
awk -f pad.awk M=$(wc -L < infile) infile
```

###Update

I missed the bit about space-padded strings. Anyway, it is fairly straightforward to allow for a variable padding character. Here is a complete example based on the ideas from above:

```
# Set padding character to the default (" ") if it was not set with -v
# Set ORS to "" to make printing easier
BEGIN { if(D == "") D = " "; ORS = "" }

# Pad each line according current line length (L) and longest line (M)
{
  L = M - length;
  for(i=1; i<=int(L/2); i++)
    print D
  print $0
  for(i=1; i<=int(L/2+.5); i++)
    print D
  print "\n"
}
```

Example:

```
awk -v M=$(wc -L < infile) -v D=_ -f pad.awk infile
```

Output:

```
_aaa_
bbbb_
__c__
ddddd
_ee__
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about `wc -L`. Ended up with this: ``awk -v M="`wc -L file`" '{ printf "%*s%*s", (M+length)/2, $1, (M-length+1)/2+1, "\n" }' < file`` after spending some time learning `awk` basics.

Comment: @Avidanborisov: nice solution, feel free to post it as an answer, or, if you prefer, add it to this answer

Comment: OK, just did :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use vim. From normal mode:

```
:%center 5
```

...will act on every line in the file (that's the meaning of the `%` in this case), centring it to five characters (referred to as columns in the vim documentation). This will act exactly as you describe. To get the longest line in a file (for use in the center command), use `wc -L file.txt`; or within vim:

```
:! wc -L %
```

Unfortunately this isn't available in vanilla vi, but since this is tagged 'linux' it's likely that you have vim in your repositories at least.

You can also do this in one line with:

```
vim file.txt -c '%center 5' -c 'wq' &> /dev/null
```

...but I'm sure that's not the fastest way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

With Python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        l = line.strip()
        print l.center(5,'.'),"\n",
```

Note: if you are using Python Old version below 2.7 then this will not work.

Same output :

```
rahul@home-pc:~/work$ python format_center.py
.aaa. 
.bbbb 
..c.. 
ddddd 
..ee.
```

Comment: The question says “the column width being the longest line from the input”. Better detect the width in your script.